# PHP Laravel search multiple tables with multiple keywords from multiple inputs

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables in db, "deals" and "deals_meta" connected between them with a foreign key.
In the "deals" table i have general information about a deal like, title, description, category etc., and in the "deals_meta" i have other specific details like, location, number of bedrooms, price, booking date and so on.

I have a form with multiple fields, title, details, booking date, price range and so on.

My problem is that i can't retrieve from db the deals based on the search query.

The code that i use to retrieve the queries looks like this:

```
$deals = Deals::where('deals_providers', $provider)->where('deal_types', $dealType)->with('meta')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($terms, $dealType) {
                $query->whereHas('meta', function ($query) use ($terms, $dealType) {
                    $search = $query->where('deal_type', 'like', '%' . $dealType . '%');
                    if ($terms['location']) {
                        $search = $query->orWhere('location', 'like', '%' . $terms['location'] . '%');
                    }
                    if ($terms['price_from']) {
                        $search = $query->orWhere('price', '>', '%' . $terms['price_from'] . '%');
                    }
                    if ($terms['price_to']) {
                        $search = $query->orWhere('price', '<', '%' . $terms['price_to'] . '%');
                    }
                    if ($terms['departs_from']) {
                        $search = $query->orWhere('departs_from', 'like', '%' . $terms['departs_from'] . '%');
                    }
                    if ($terms['duration']) {
                        $search = $query->orWhere('duration', 'like', '%' . $terms['duration'] . '%');
                    }
                    if ($terms['available_start']) {
                        $search = $query->orWHere('available_start', 'like', '%' . $terms['available_start'] . '%');
                    }
                    if ($terms['available_end']) {
                        $search = $query->orWhere('available_end', 'like', '%' . $terms['available_end'] . '%');
                    }

                    return $search;
                });
                if ($terms['title']) {
                    $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $terms['title'] . '%');
                }
                if ($terms['details']) {
                    $query->orWhere('details', 'like', '%' . $terms['details'], '%');
                }
            })->get();

        Debug::data($deals);
```

If i search for title or details, it returns only the deals that have that title or contains that details but if i search for location or any other meta related term, it returns all the deals results from the db.
What i'm doing wrong or how can i search corectly?

Thank you!

Comment: At first your code is bad quaility, check DRY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself.

Comment: That's not an answer...bad or not bad, stick to the subject please or else don't comment!

Comment: P.S. please explain yourself...where i repeted myself?

Comment: So, that's it?
You commented that my code is bad and no feedback to tell me why is bad?
Please explain?!

Comment: Your ifs can be just one loop thought the terms array using the array key to access to the value, and in case in the future you add new attributes to the Deals it will still working without add more ifs. You can make a post on code review after someone answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

This is the code that works for my case!

```
$deals = Deals::where('deals_providers', $provider)->where('deal_types', $dealType)->with('meta')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($terms, $dealType) {
            $query->whereHas('meta', function ($query) use ($terms, $dealType) {
                if ($terms['location']) {
                    $query->where('location', 'like', '%' . $terms['location'] . '%');
                }
                if ($terms['price_from'] && $terms['price_to']) {
                    $query->whereBetween('price', [$terms['price_from'], $terms['price_to']]);
                }
                if ($terms['departs_from']) {
                    $query->where('departs_from', 'like', '%' . $terms['departs_from'] . '%');
                }
                if ($terms['duration']) {
                    $query->where('duration', 'like', '%' . $terms['duration'] . '%');
                }
                if ($terms['available_start']) {
                    $query->where('available_start', 'like', '%' . $terms['available_start'] . '%');
                }
                if ($terms['available_end']) {
                    $query->where('available_end', 'like', '%' . $terms['available_end'] . '%');
                }
            });
            if ($terms['title']) {
                $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . $terms['title'] . '%');
            }
            if ($terms['details']) {
                $query->orWhere('details', 'like', '%' . $terms['details'], '%');
            }
        })->get();

    Debug::data($deals);
```